# Default webcam driver issues

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers, webcam

I'm having troubles getting my monitor-attached webcam (ASUS VK248H) to install on my new computer. On the old computer, it was a matter of not using a USB 3.0 port, but I can't get anything to work on the new one. I have tried all manner of uninstalling/reinstalling the driver and resetting the computer, as well as literally every USB port on the computer (14 in total).

It's not that windows isn't recognizing the device; it most certainly is. However, comparing it to the old computer's driver details, on the new computer, it is not using the ksthunk.sys driver in addition to the usbvideo.sys driver, like on the old (working) computer. Naturally, I figured the way ahead was to simply get this other driver to work with the hardware, but haven't really found out a way to do that.

Does anyone know of a way I can force it to use ksthunk.sys? It seems rather difficult to get it to install anything when Windows is feeling that everything is peachy.